# Problema con funciones en Tkinter - Python

Tags: python, funciones, tkinter

antes que todo pido disculpas si no formulo correctamente mi consulta, ya que es la primera vez que hago una por este medio. Dicho esto y yendo al punto, me encuentro realizando un programa con Python, Pytube y Tkinter, el cual consiste en que, según la url que le damos, podemos descargar tanto video como audio, y así también videos individuales como playlist. Este es un fragmento del código:

```
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import os
import pytube

# Ventana main
ventana = Tk()
ventana.title('akaDownloader')
ventana.minsize(540, 420)
ventana.resizable(0, 0)
ventana.iconbitmap('C:/Users/danie/Desktop/Proyectos Programación/YoutubeDownloader/logo.ico')
ventana.configure(bg='#2E2D2C')

# Ruta default
carpeta_default = "C:/Users/danie/Desktop/Proyectos Programación/YoutubeDownloader/Videos"

# Funciones
def descargar_video_video():
    try:
        video_url = url.get()
        youtube = pytube.YouTube(video_url)
        video = youtube.streams.first()
        titulo = youtube.title
        descarga = video.download(carpeta_default)

        archivo_nuevo = titulo+'.mp4'
        os.chdir(carpeta_default)
        os.rename(descarga, archivo_nuevo)
        notif_descarga.config(fg="green", text="La descarga fue exitosa")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        notif_descarga.config(fg="red", text="No se completó la descarga")

def descargar_video_audio():
    try:
        video_url = url.get()
        youtube = pytube.YouTube(video_url)
        video = youtube.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
        titulo = youtube.title
        descarga = video.download(carpeta_default)

        archivo_nuevo = titulo+'.mp3'
        os.chdir(carpeta_default)
        os.rename(descarga, archivo_nuevo)
        notif_descarga.config(fg="green", text="La descarga fue exitosa")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        notif_descarga.config(fg="red", text="No se completó la descarga")

def descargar_playlist_video():
    playlist_url = url.get()
    playlist = pytube.contrib.playlist.Playlist(playlist_url)
    playlist_list = playlist.video_urls
    for videoUrl in playlist_list:
        try:
            yt = pytube.YouTube(videoUrl)
            titulo = yt.title
            video = yt.streams.first()
            descarga = video.download(carpeta_default)

            archivo_nuevo = titulo+'.mp4'
            os.chdir(carpeta_default)
            os.rename(descarga, archivo_nuevo)
            notif_descarga.config(fg="green", text="La descarga fue exitosa")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            notif_descarga.config(fg="red", text="No se completó la descarga")

def descargar_playlist_audio():
    playlist_url = url.get()
    playlist = pytube.contrib.playlist.Playlist(playlist_url)
    playlist_list = playlist.video_urls
    for videoUrl in playlist_list:
        try:
            yt = pytube.YouTube(videoUrl)
            titulo = yt.title
            video = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first()
            descarga = video.download(carpeta_default)

            archivo_nuevo = titulo+'.mp3'
            os.chdir(carpeta_default)
            os.rename(descarga, archivo_nuevo)
            notif_descarga.config(fg="green", text="La descarga fue exitosa")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            notif_descarga.config(fg="red", text="No se completó la descarga")
def cambiar_carpeta_default():
    global carpeta_default
    carpeta_default = filedialog.askdirectory()
    notif_carpeta.config(fg="green", text=carpeta_default)

# Pantalla main
home_label = Label(ventana, text="akaDownloader")
home_label.config(
    fg="red",
    # bg="black",
    bg="#1F1E1D",
    font=("Arial", 20),
    padx=176,
    pady=7
)
home_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=12)

Label(ventana, text="Descargar video", fg="red", font=("Calibri", 15, "bold"), bg='#2E2D2C').grid(sticky=NW, padx=200, row=3, column = 0)
Label(ventana, text="Ingrese el link del video a descargar", font=("Calibri", 10, "bold"), bg='#2E2D2C', fg='white').grid(sticky=NW, row=4, padx=10, pady=5)
url = StringVar()
Entry(ventana, width=50, textvariable=url).grid(sticky=NW, padx=10, row=5)
# Button(ventana, width=20,text="Download",font=("Calibri",12),command=descargar_video).grid(sticky=NW, row=6, padx=10, pady=5) this
Button(ventana, width=15,text="Descargar video",font=("Calibri",12),command=descargar_video_video).grid(sticky=NW, row=6, padx=10, pady=5)
Button(ventana, width=15,text="Descargar audio",font=("Calibri",12),command=descargar_video_audio).grid(sticky=NW, row=6, padx=150, pady=5)

Label(ventana, text="Descargar playlist", fg="red", font=("Calibri", 15, "bold"), bg='#2E2D2C').grid(sticky=NW, padx=190, row=7)
Label(ventana, text="Ingrese el link de la playlist a descargar", font=("Calibri", 10, "bold"), bg='#2E2D2C', fg='white').grid(sticky=NW, row=8, padx=10, pady=5)
url = StringVar()
Entry(ventana, width=50, textvariable=url).grid(sticky=NW, padx=10, row=9)
# Button(ventana, width=20,text="Download",font=("Calibri",12),command=descargar_playlist_video).grid(sticky=NW, row=10, padx=10, pady=5)
Button(ventana, width=15,text="Descargar video",font=("Calibri",12),command=descargar_playlist_video).grid(sticky=NW, row=10, padx=10, pady=5)
Button(ventana, width=15,text="Descargar audio",font=("Calibri",12),command=descargar_playlist_audio).grid(sticky=NW, row=10, padx=150, pady=5)

#Notification descarga
notif_descarga = Label(ventana,font=("Calibri",12), bg='#2E2D2C')
notif_descarga.grid(sticky=NW, padx=180, pady=1,row=19)

#Choose path
Label(ventana,text="Cambiar carpeta de destino",font=("Calibri", 10, "bold"), bg='#2E2D2C', fg='white').grid(sticky=NW,row=16, padx=10)
Button(ventana,width=15,text="Elegir carpeta",font=("Calibri",12),command=cambiar_carpeta_default).grid(sticky=NW,row=17, padx=10, pady=5)

#Notification Path
notif_carpeta= Label(ventana,font=("Calibri",8), bg='#2E2D2C')
notif_carpeta.grid(sticky=NW,row=18,pady=15, padx=10)

ventana.mainloop()
```

[image: Así es como se ve el programa]

El problema radica en que en cuanto ingreso una url y doy click en cualquier botón para ejecutar una función, por ejemplo, en `Descargar video` (`descargar_video_video`), devuelve el siguiente error `regex_search: could not find match for (?:v=|\/)([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11}).*`, pero lo curioso es que si pulso todos los demás botones (o sea, ejecuto las demás funciones de descarga), el video/audio se descarga correctamente y el programa funciona como debe ser. Al borrar, por ejemplo el código que refiere a playlist en la UI, las funciones de descarga de video funcionan correctamente, y viceversa si borro el código de video en la UI, las funciones de descarga de playlist funcionan sin problema.

Ya intenté colocando las funciones en un archivo separado, utilizando funciones lambda y también intenté invocar las funciones con parámetro pero no he tenido suerte. Les agradecería su ayuda y disculpen si la pregunta se hizo larga.

Comment: Estás usando el mismo nombre de variable, `url`, para las dos `StringVars` que usas. Las funciones sólo trabajarán con la última. ¿Ése es el problema que te está pasando?

Comment: Exacto, como comentó @abulafia, estaba sobreescribiendo la variable ``url``, corrigiendo eso el script funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que sobreescribes la variable global `url`.

Primero la usas para referirte al `StringVar` del primer `Entry`:

```
url = StringVar()
Entry(ventana, width=50, textvariable=url).grid(sticky=NW, padx=10, row=5)
```

Pero más adelante haces lo mismo para la segunda entrada (la de las playlist):

```
url = StringVar()
Entry(ventana, width=50, textvariable=url).grid(sticky=NW, padx=10, row=9)
```

Por tanto a partir de este punto, la variable `url` se refiere a la segunda (la de la playlist). Cuando se pulsa el botón y se invoca `descargar_video_video()`, y ésta función intenta acceder a `url.get()` está accediendo al contenido del segundo `Entry`, en vez del primero.

La solución es obviamente tener diferentes variables para referirse al `StringVar` del vídeo y el de la lista. Esto implica modificar también el código de las funciones de descarga para que en lugar de `url.get()` usen por ejemplo `url_video.get()` o `url_list.get()` según corresponda.

Puedo confirmarte que haciendo esos cambios el script funciona correctamente, porque lo he testeado.

Comment: Efectivamente, éste era el problema. Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responder y también de testear, ya funciona todo correctamente :D Saludos!